# ajaxFileUpload have more params than "file"

Tags: jquery

Can i have more param to send to the url: using ajaxFileUpload ?

Im using $.ajaxFileUpload() and when I ajax the fileupload i want to pass a extra param with it too. Im only passing a param called "file" with the file you are uploading in it..
The settings look like this:

```
url:'photo.php?mode=upload',
secureuri:false,
type: 'post',
fileElementId:'file',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data, status)
```

tried adding data: { param : '1' } but it doesnt pass anything..

Answer (score 5):

data: { 'id': id }

ex:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload
     (
         {
             url: 'SampleReportEditHandler.html',
             secureuri: false,
             fileElementId: 'UploadFile',
             data: { 'id': '100' }
             beforeSend: function () {},
             success: function (data, status) {},
             error: function (data, status, e) {}
         }
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you accomplish your goal by adding another GET parameter to the URL?

`url:'photo.php?mode=upload&file=someFileName'`

I'm not entirely familiar with this jquery plugin. Are you sure it supports param?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data parameter.
Data should be a javascript object for example:

```
data ={name:'my name', description:'short description'}
```

And then use this data with ajaxFileUpload

```
$.ajaxFileUpload
(
  {
    url:url, 
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'fileElementId'
  }
)
```

If you want to fetch form elements, you can get data as following:

```
var data = {};
$("#" + formId + " :input").each(function(){data[this.name]=this.value});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the jQuery [ajax form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), but ajaxFileUpload looks like it works the same way.  You can set the datatype to "json" or "xml", and it should send all the fields in your form to the url.

Comment: please see updated question for better explanation. I want to send a more postparam, it only pass 1, the 'file' that contains the file you are uploading, now i wish to pass another one, but cant get it to work

Comment: I took a closer look at the ajaxfileupload code and I take back my previous answer (actually on the ajaxFileUpload page it says that it only submits the file type input element).  You could wrap the function call for ajaxFileUpload in a $(form).submit handler and submit any extra parameters you needed to with a seperate request.